# Pass in a generator / mocking function to a method in a legacy module

Tags: python, generator, python-2.x, legacy-code

In Python, I have a legacy module `Utils` with a `legacy` method, like this:

```
@staticmethod
def legacy(users, some_data, other_data):
    j=0
    for _ in users.keys():
        do_something([{'a': some_data[j], 'b': other_data[j]}])
        j=j+1
```

I'm writing a new logic where only `users` and `some_data` exists, and `other_data` does not exist.

I'm thinking of passing in a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) / mocking method so that i can do:

```
Utils.legacy(users, some_data, magic)
```

which sets `{'b': magic[j]}` given a specific `j`.

Is there a way to implement the `magic` using generator / some mocking?

Notes:

- the legacy code cannot be changed
- the above simplied question can be solved by passing in a `dict` of size of users, but i'm looking for a more general solution.

Comment: First of all, you can't use a generator because they cannot be indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a class with a `__getitem__` method that doesn't put any constraints on its argument.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        pass


Utils.legacy(users, some_data, Foo())
```

Replace `pass` with `return foo` for whatever placeholder element `foo` you'd like.

Or, on second thought, use `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

Utils.legacy(users, some_data, defaultdict(lambda: None))
```

(Or use any other zero-argument function to provide a default value in place of `lambda: None`.)

Comment: fior yet another layer, e.g. `'c':yet_some_data[0][j]`, a nested solution works: `class NestedFoo():
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Foo()`

Comment: You don't even need a separate class. Just return another instance of the same class: `class Foo(): def __getitem__(self, key): return Foo()`. Then no matter how deeply you try to index it, the resulting value is still indexible :)